# Fixture error when running test Hartl Chapter 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, fixtures

I'm at the last section of Chapter 8 and need my last test suite to be green before pushing to Heroku. For some reason I'm getting an error that I think dates back to Chapter 6 when I was creating users (had some issues then).

Here's the following error:

```
  1) Failure:
SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil
[/Users/carlosgrijalva/workspace/sample_app/test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#<User id: 762146111, name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com", 
created_at: "2016-07-20 14:56:07", updated_at: "2016-07-20 14:56:12", 
password_digest: "$2a$04$ll9WRPhi4/y65RgRqiMwiO4evjbp8mR1FwCTIkdZsMA...", 
remember_digest: "$2a$04$IOc/zghNtUBNFi45l96DwOc7YYUT2f2BJsob5wLg/c0...">
+nil
```

**users_login_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    remember(@user)
  end

  test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end
end
```

**users.yml**

```
michael:
  name: Michael Hartl
  email: mhartl@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Now, I think this goes back to Chapter 6 when I was playing around with users. I ended up deleting the first one I created and ended up making 2 users with different names/emails:

*first user*

```
2.3.1 :001 > User.first
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Rails Tutorial", email: "example@railstutorial.com", 
created_at: "2016-07-05 21:54:47", 
updated_at: "2016-07-05 21:54:47", 
password_digest: "$2a$10$KH0GTDtLldSCWy6xAUebZuFH11U7DPmkT6uZAZQ0xf2...", 
remember_digest: nil>
```

*second user*

```
2.3.1 :002 > User.second
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
 => #<User id: 2, name: "Example User2", email: "example2@railstutorial.com", 
created_at: "2016-07-07 18:17:20", updated_at: "2016-07-19 21:40:31",   
password_digest: "$2a$10$GzAoNK2GDp5ne1hTb70jDuO8m1ydthy879Xto/gJpWx...", 
remember_digest: "$2a$10$I/yQhO/HLNkGF9aUk9ldMeZvuBHYK2akM1b0at1n1bk...">
```

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the error but it seemed relevant. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what does the is_logged_in? method in the test look like

Comment: # Returns true if a test user is logged in.

  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end